# Scrape videos using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape videos from **any url** that is entered by the user. The problem is that as I don't know the name of the video, or the specific website, I have no idea what I'm looking for. I tried using BeautifulSoup like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
r = requests.get(Web_url)
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

video_tags = soup.findAll('video')
 
for video_tag in video_tags:
    video_url = video_tag.find("a")['href']
    print(video_url)
```

But from what I can tell this may only work if the video is inside the html. I've tried alot of websites with this and nothing seems to show up. I've also tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
videos = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'video')
for video in videos:
    print(video.get_attribute('src'))
```

But this gave me the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"video"}   (Session info: headless chrome=107.0.5304.107)
```

I'm not sure what else to try. Alot of resources on google are for scraping Youtube videos specifically and half of those tell me to use a Youtube download module. I'd appreciate any help with this problem. Thanks

Comment: I would not use something as complex as selenium for this. Instead you can use yt-dl or yt-dlp (yt-dlp is better imo). https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp

Comment: @SollyBunny This won't help as Youtube is not the only website this program will work for

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this list](https://gist.github.com/sky-y/1fac37a3c9db71e6af78), before dismissing yt-dl

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Fair enough some websites are better than none right?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this isn't possible. At least with Selenium. Because each website have it own page structures etc. So you can't predict the elements you want to access on each possible website.

Comment: I guess I could also take the yt-dl approach and manually code each website, I just hoped there was some way of easily getting around something likr that

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately AFAIK this is not possible

Answer (score 0):

You can analyse network traffic. You have to look for mimeType of network packages. If mimeType contains 'video' or 'vnd.apple.mpegurl' then you can take the package's url, that's the video url you are looking for.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time, json

def process_logs(logs):
    for entry in logs:
        log = json.loads(entry['message'])['message']
        if 'Network.response' in log['method'] or 'Network.request' in log['method'] or 'Network.webSocket' in log['method']:
            yield log

def extract_video_link(events):
    for event in events:
        try:
            mime_type = event['params']['response']['mimeType']
            link = event['params']['response']['url']
            if 'vnd.apple.mpegurl' in mime_type or 'video' in mime_type:
                yield link
        except Exception:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Startup the chrome webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    # Send a request to the website and let it load
    driver.get(YOUR_LINK)

    # Sleeps for 5 seconds
    time.sleep(2)

    # Gets all the logs from performance in Chrome
    logs = driver.get_log('performance')

    # Extract only network traffic
    events = process_logs(logs)

    # Extract all video links
    video_links = extract_video_link(events)

    print(list(video_links))
```